# ReactJS render() { return() }

Tags: reactjs

Подскажите пожалуйста разницу написания между:

```
render() {
    return(
        <Button>test</Button>
    )
}
```

и

```
render() {
    let testButton = (
        <Button>test</Button>
    )
    return(
        {testButton}
    )
}
```

Comment: Никакой разницы. Кому как нравится

Answer (score 1):

Второй не сработает. Потому что лишние скобки {} заставляют возвращать метод render обычный javascript объект а не jsx компонент. Надо так:

```
render() {
    let testButton = (
        <Button>test</Button>
    )
    return(
        testButton
    )
}
```

Вот если написать так - никакой разницы нет. Почему нет? Потому что jsx транслируется в js, и первый и второй варианты преобразуются почти в эквивалентный js.

Посмотреть как транслирует jsx например babel [можно тут.](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&code=)

То что для других трансляторов jsx код должен быть таким же по смыслу, я не уверен на 100%. Уверен на 99.9%. Увериться на 100% можно погрузившись в [официальную спецификацию jsx.](http://facebook.github.io/jsx/)

Почитать человеческим языком про нюансы jsx можно [в документации от фейсбука](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html)